# How to hide a UIView and set new height to UITable view in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UITable view in my View controller and a stackview at the bottom of the table view. I want the UITable view to go full view when stackview isHidden. Here is the code i write to do so :

```
                if response.total != 0.0{
                checkoutStackView.layoutIfNeeded()
                medDetailTableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                medDetailTableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
                vwPlaceOrder.isHidden = true
                viewCheckout.isHidden = true
                checkoutStackView.isHidden = true
            }else{
                checkoutStackView.layoutIfNeeded()
                viewCheckout.isHidden = false
                checkoutStackView.isHidden = false
                self.vwPlaceOrder.isHidden = false
                self.lblTotalItemsPrice.text = String(format: "%.1f",response.total)
                medDetailTableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                medDetailTableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -70.0).isActive = true
            }
```

But this code is only showing the stackview but when the stackview is hidden UITableview is not going full view.
Here is a image when stackview is showing:
[image]
And here is the image when stackview is hidden:
[image]

Comment: You are not handling the constraints properly. You need to deactivate or remove one before adding a new one to the same anchor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you hide a view in Swift , it just make it hide but constraints of hiden view is still alive. So you must to set 0 this height constraints.

For this you can create an outlet of Constraints and change it like :

```
  @IBOutlet weak var heightConstt: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

And when you hide stackView change its constraint

```
  heightConstt.constant = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [footer view of UITableView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614976-tablefooterview) for placing your view. And make UITableView full size of it's superview.
It should solve your problem.